# mongoose getting all from collection returns back an empty list

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I created a new collection in my project and followed the same syntax for retrieving all users to retrieve all from this collection but I end up getting an empty array or list for some reason. Can someone please let me know why that is as I am fairly new to MongoDB. below is my code. the service is being called as I put a console.log before the query and it is called. Also saving data to the DB also works its just getAll I am having trouble doing. the collection only has one field which is account number.

In the service I have

```
async function getAll() {
    return await accountdb.find({});
}
```

controller

```
function getAll(req, res, next) {
    accountdbService.getAll()
        .then(account => res.json(account))
        .catch(err => next(err));
}
```

in the front end i have

```
 getAll() {
    return this.http.get<account[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/account`);
  }
```

and finally in the component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadAllAccounts();
  }

  private loadAllAccounts() {
    this.AccountService.getAll().pipe(first()).subscribe(account => {
      this.accounts = account;
      console.log(this.accounts);
    });
    console.log(this.accounts);
```

}

postman response when calling api:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5b89e647e1e6540ac28d68b1",
        "logDataInput": "admin changed the status of user test2 to manager",
        "__v": 0,
        "id": "5b89e647e1e6540ac28d68b1"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b89e648e1e6540ac28d68b2",
        "logDataInput": "admin changed the status of user test2 to User",
        "__v": 0,
        "id": "5b89e648e1e6540ac28d68b2"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b8a2a6b16206e0cae8c71ba",
        "logDataInput": "admin deactivated user test2",
        "__v": 0,
        "id": "5b8a2a6b16206e0cae8c71ba"
    }
]
```

[network tool 2 api calls picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snA1k.png)

Comment: What happens when you hit this API from Postman? Does that return the required data?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help first of all, secondly i cant get postman to work it requires basic auth which i cant get to work

Comment: Can't you just send the basic auth header as you would do in Angular?

Comment: Exactly. You can do that on Postman.

Comment: It seems you're using `async/await` in the service, but then still calling `.then` on it from the controller

Comment: Another disturbing thing is that you're doing `async function getAll() {
    return await accountdb.find({});
}` on your Angular client when it should have been in a Node project and exposed as an API.

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera it is in a node project and exposed i just listed all of them here

Comment: @user184994 can you tell me what i put in the basic auth header? do i put the secret? how is it structured, i cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: Do you have the Node API beployed somewhere? If yes, please consider creating a stackblitz. If no, tell us what is the response that you get when you hit this API in Postman.

Comment: @z123 Well if it's sending the header in Angular, just copy and paste it from the network tab of the developer tools. Otherwise, the value is something like `Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz`, where the second bit is a base64 encoded copy of the username and password, separated with a `:`

Comment: @user184994 thanks that helped. Finally got postman working and i posted the response from the api above. I seem to get the three values i put my default. But why is it that the array is empty

Comment: Okay, so postman works as expected, Angular gives you an empty array, yes? If you check the response in the developer tools network tab, is it empty in the response?

Comment: @user184994 in the network developer tool i see two calls to the same api one empty and one has the responses i requested i posted a pic of the two calls above from the developer tools

Comment: The first one is probably an OPTIONS preflight, and the second one is the actual request. So if the data is coming back in the response, where are you getting an empty array?

Comment: @user184994 so in the component i have a load users functions oninit that loads all the users from the api to a local list of that object and when u check that it is empty.

Comment: If you add a `console.log(account)` **inside the subscribe** function, are the values printed?

Comment: @user184994 yes so i pinpointed it down to the this.accounts = account; not working i initialized it in the component as accounts: Accounts[] = [];

Comment: So is this working now?

Comment: no, for some reason after it goes out of the subscrible() this.accounts is an empty array again

Comment: Can you edit your code above to show how you're checking it?

Comment: @user184994 so i added 2 console.log statements, the first one is populated with the values and the one outside of the subscibe is empty

Comment: @z123 I've added an answer below that explains the reason it logs an empty array, but I don't think there's actually any bugs here, just async code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is, the `getAll()` function is asynchronous, that is to say the code directly after may be executed before the `subscribe` function is.

It looks like your array is being set but, by checking it outside of the subscribe, you're checking it *before* it's been set.

Comment: thanks you are right i checked with another api and that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're sending wrong variable in response from getAll function.

```
    .then(logTrack => res.json(account)
```

Chage this to

```
    .then(logTrack => res.json(logTrack)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that is not the issue that was put in here by accident i fixed it.